# libpng error: Read Error when using matplotlib after setting usetex=True

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex, libpng

On two different machines running Windows 10, I am getting the error `libpng error: Read Error` leading to python crashing when trying to plot after setting the option `usetex=True` in matplotlib. This has worked without problems before on this machine, I am not sure what changed since.

I have tried installing different libpng versions (1.6.32, 1.6.34, 1.6.36, 1.6.37) but all of them lead to the same outcome.

A minimum example, directly after creating a fresh environment with `conda create --name libpngtest python=3 matplotlib libpng`:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from matplotlib import rc
>>> rc('text', usetex=True)
>>> plt.plot(1,2)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000193015A8908>]
>>> plt.show()
```

At this point sometimes the python console just crashes out without any message, but I have also seen `libpng error: Read Error` printed before it crashes. Inside a jupyter notebook/lab, the kernel will restart and `libpng error: Read Error` appears in the terminal where jupyter is running between jupyter messages.

At this point I am not sure if this is a python problem or a TeX problem (I have MikTeX 2.9 installed, which seems to be running fine), but would appreciate any hints you may have.

---

Edit: The output after setting `plt.set_loglevel("debug")` is:

```
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: serif, font: Computer Modern Roman, info: ('cmr', '')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:sans-serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:sans-serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: sans-serif, font: Computer Modern Sans Serif, info: ('cmss', '')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:cursive font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:cursive font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: cursive, font: Zapf Chancery, info: ('pzc', '\\usepackage{chancery}')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:monospace font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:monospace font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: monospace, font: Computer Modern Typewriter, info: ('cmtt', '')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:following keys changed: ['text.latex.preamble', 'text.latex.unicode', 'text.latex.preview', 'font.family', 'font.serif', 'font.sans-serif', 'font.cursive', 'font.monospace']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:text.latex.preamble : None       ->
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:text.latex.unicode  : None       -> True
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:text.latex.preview  : None       -> False
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:font.family         : None       -> ['sans-serif']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:font.serif          : None       -> ['DejaVu Serif', 'Bitstream Vera Serif', 'Computer Modern Roman', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Utopia', 'ITC Bookman', 'Bookman', 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'Times New Roman', 'Times', 'Palatino', 'Charter', 'serif']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:font.sans-serif     : None       -> ['DejaVu Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Computer Modern Sans Serif', 'Lucida Grande', 'Verdana', 'Geneva', 'Lucid', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Avant Garde', 'sans-serif']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:font.cursive        : None       -> ['Apple Chancery', 'Textile', 'Zapf Chancery', 'Sand', 'Script MT', 'Felipa', 'cursive']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:font.monospace      : None       -> ['DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Computer Modern Typewriter', 'Andale Mono', 'Nimbus Mono L', 'Courier New', 'Courier', 'Fixed', 'Terminal', 'monospace']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:RE-INIT
old fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: serif, font: Computer Modern Roman, info: ('cmr', '')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:sans-serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:sans-serif font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: sans-serif, font: Computer Modern Sans Serif, info: ('cmss', '')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:cursive font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:cursive font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: cursive, font: Zapf Chancery, info: ('pzc', '\\usepackage{chancery}')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:monospace font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:monospace font is not compatible with usetex.
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:family: monospace, font: Computer Modern Typewriter, info: ('cmtt', '')
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\1acea6f6c115d0ec7a634ed0529287b9.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:['kpsewhich', 'cmss10.tfm']
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:stdout:
b'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmss10.tfm\r\n'
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:stderr:
b''
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:opening tfm file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmss10.tfm
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:lh=18, bc=0, ec=127, nw=52, nh=16, nd=11
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:['kpsewhich', 'cmss10.vf']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\d598be7bdc6e0eeebdc83c75321a7705.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:['kpsewhich', 'cmr10.tfm']
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:stdout:
b'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm\r\n'
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:stderr:
b''
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:opening tfm file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:lh=18, bc=0, ec=127, nw=36, nh=16, nd=10
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:['kpsewhich', 'cmr10.vf']
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:['kpsewhich', 'cmmi10.tfm']
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:stdout:
b'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm\r\n'
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:stderr:
b''
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:opening tfm file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmmi10.tfm
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:lh=18, bc=0, ec=127, nw=98, nh=15, nd=9
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:['kpsewhich', 'cmmi10.vf']
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\1acea6f6c115d0ec7a634ed0529287b9.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\14cf46b44d83e91d3e4f12cc60007df3.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\1acea6f6c115d0ec7a634ed0529287b9.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\217de38979bbb592496a29d181b7bbc4.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\1acea6f6c115d0ec7a634ed0529287b9.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\3233f296f4d6994ca99a0d418d6458d8.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\1acea6f6c115d0ec7a634ed0529287b9.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi: C:\Users\...\.matplotlib\tex.cache\e2c00e1750b187927439ebc0ca3a1a38.dvi
DEBUG:matplotlib.dviread:Dvi._xxx: encountered special: papersize=5203.43999pt,5203.43999pt
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
DEBUG:matplotlib.texmanager:fontconfig: sans-serifcmrcmsspzccmttd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Comment: Was there a LaTex log file generated?

Comment: @WilliamMiller that's an interesting question. There is no LaTeX log file in the directory from which I'm running python. Would it be generated somewhere else? I looked in my `MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log` directory and I see `kpsewhich` is finishing with exit code 1 every time it gets run on a `.vf` file. This seems a likely cause of the problem...

Comment: Although for what it's worth this was already happening years ago, when these commands ran without any issue.

Comment: Afraid I’m not sure where it would be generated in a case like this. Is this happening consistently?

Comment: Yes, every single time I generate a plot with `usetex=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to skirt around the issue, though I would not call it a solution (with credit to anntzer on the matplotlib github repo, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16163). From matplotlib 3.2.0 libpng will no longer be used, so installing matplotlib 3.2.0-rc is a possible workaround.